# when using open and close brackets and when not

Tags: php, if-statement

I saw this piece of code which does not use a bracket or : before the if/else statement. I thought that every statement should start with **{** or **:** 
What is the reason they do not use it here?

```
if (!$this->Article)
        throw NotFoundException('Article');

    // Set required permission.
    $UserModel = new UserModel();
    if ($this->Article->Status != ArticleModel::STATUS_PUBLISHED)
        if (($this->Article->AttributionUserID == Gdn::Session()->UserID)
            && !$UserModel->CheckPermission($this->Article->AttributionUserID, 'Articles.Articles.Edit')
        )
            $this->Permission('Articles.Articles.View');
        else
            $this->Permission('Articles.Articles.Edit');
    else
        $this->Permission('Articles.Articles.View');
```

Comment: If you don't use { and } with an if or else or ifelse, only the next line of code will be included. The indentation is horrendous, so it doesn't make it easy to see that is what they are doing.

Comment: Single line statements in a control structure don't require braces.  Personally, I use them regardless for the consistency.

Comment: That code is nearly unreadable - where does it come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't forget the edge case on calculating your code coverage with phpunit:

```
<?php
// Because it is "line based" and not statement base coverage
// one line will always have one coverage status
if (false) this_function_call_shows_up_as_covered();

// Due to how code coverage works internally these two lines are special.
// This line will show up as non executable
if (false)
    // This line will show up as covered because it is actually the 
    // coverage of the if statement in the line above that gets shown here!
    will_also_show_up_as_coveraged();

// To avoid this it is necessary that braces are used
if (false) {
    this_call_will_never_show_up_as_covered();
}
?>
```

See https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.edge-cases for more information.

Imo this is one reason why it is best practice to use always brackets, an other is, debugging such code you give as example is very annoying.

Comment: Thanks. it is now clear to me

Answer (score 1):

You use brackets to indicate to the interpreter where the `if` statement starts and stops. However, when the `if` statement only consists of one line, the brackets can be omitted and the interpreter conditionally executes (or not) the next line.

Whether or not this is a good practice is debatable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 or more operators in `if` statement always use brackets. If one operator, you can skip them.

But i suggest to always use brackets.

Answer (score 0):

If the code that must to run in case the if  statement returns true will have just a single line, you do not need the brackets. brackets in if statement are required just in case of more than one row of code inside it.

Answer (score 0):

if the code between the "if" statement consists of one line you can get rid of bracket "{" but if the code of the "if" statement is consists of more than line you must use it

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the brackets when there is only one sentence to execute, or there is only one control statement... in this code:

```
if (!$this->Article)
    throw NotFoundException('Article'); //Only one sentence


// Set required permission.
$UserModel = new UserModel();
if ($this->Article->Status != ArticleModel::STATUS_PUBLISHED)
    //Insde there is only one if/else
    if (($this->Article->AttributionUserID == Gdn::Session()->UserID)
        && !$UserModel->CheckPermission($this->Article->AttributionUserID, 'Articles.Articles.Edit')
    )
        //Inside there is only one sentence
        $this->Permission('Articles.Articles.View');
    else
        //Else statement contains only one sentence
        $this->Permission('Articles.Articles.Edit');
else
    //Else statement contains only one sentence
    $this->Permission('Articles.Articles.View');
```

---

In the first example if you want to execute 2 sentences, it must be enclosed in brackets like this:

```
if (!$this->Article)
{
    $foo = true;
    throw NotFoundException('Article'); 
}
```

Regards

Comment: You mentioned on a now-deleted question that PHP does not have an `endif` statement. In fact, it does indeed have one: the `if ():` - `endif` construct is popular for writing template files, since the ending of the clause is more visible inside PHP tags than a closing brace.

Comment: I was getting ready to comment the exact same thing with [a link to the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) about alternate syntax before that answer was deleted.

Comment: yeah, my bad. I forgot the alternate syntax. ;)